# Two Dataset for two secondary axis y in ggplot R

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

first dataset = df

```
Date variable value 
1    A          6
1    B          2
1    C          0.8
2    A          8
2    B          3
2    C          2
3    A          11
3    B          2
3    C          4
```

second dataset = met

```
Date variable value
 1     H       140.000
 2     H       70.000
 3     H       150.000
```

What I am doing, but it is not working

```
  ggplot() 
+ geom_line(df, mapping = aes(x=date, y=value, fill=variable, color = variable, linetype=variable)) 
+ geom_line(met, mapping = aes(x=date,y=value, color="blue")) 
+ scale_y_continuous(name = "First Axis", sec.axis = sec_axis(~.1, name="Second Axis"))
      
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
Warning message: 
Ignoring unknown aesthetics: fill
```

At the same time I have another question. Is it possibile to set 2 ylim? One for the left side and the other one for the right side.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You were close, but had a few small mistakes in your code:

1. R is case-sensitive so `Date` is not the same as `date`.
2. A small tweak to the syntax of providing a formula to the `sec_axis` transformation
3. If you're making an aesthetic fixed rather than mapping to a data variable (e.g. `color = "blue"` vs `color = variable`) then you probably want to put it outside `aes()` to avoid creating a legend for it. Unless that was your intent, in which case ignore this point.
4. If you're transforming the second axis to show some of the data on a different scale, you probably need to transform that data too. Thus, you'll see in the second `geom_line` layer I set `y = 10*value` to compensate.

In answer to your question about 2 different `ylim` values - no. The second axis is a linear transformation of the first and its limits need to be the same transformation of the limits on the first. The numbers displayed are just that, a displayed value. If you want to change limits, you need to be in a separate plot, for example a [faceted plot](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_grid.html) with `scales = "free_y"`.

```r
# load packages
library(tidyverse)

# set up data
df <- structure(list(Date = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
                     variable = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"), 
                     value = c(6, 2, 0.8, 8, 3, 2, 11, 2, 4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                   -9L))
met <- structure(list(Date = 1:3, variable = c("H", "H", "H"), value = c(140, 
                                                                         70, 150)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
# plot calling each dataset in separate geom layers
ggplot() +
  geom_line(df,
            mapping = aes(
              x = Date,
              y = 10 * value,
              color = variable,
              linetype = variable
            )) +
  geom_line(met, mapping = aes(x = Date, y = value), color = "blue") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "First Axis",
                     sec.axis = sec_axis( ~ . * .1, name = "Second Axis"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work, I think I have problems with tidyverse. I have a dataset that is much longer than this one of the example. How can I trasform all the dataset like as you did?

Comment: This are pretty basic `{dplyr}` and `{ggplot2}` functions, so I doubt your problem is the package version. But if you suspect that, it will help if you provide the output of `sessionInfo()` in your question.

Comment: Also, this solution **does** work with the sample data you provided. So in order to get help, you need to provide the smallest subset of your actual data that reproduces the problem. But the approach here `select`ing columns using `seq()` to get every other column should work no matter how large the dataset is provided you have the same number of columns in each.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't get the seq(). In the function read.table(header = T, text= I have my df and naturally it gives me the error. But I don't know how to entirely transform it in text). How can use it in this case?

Comment: Sorry, the `seq()` comment was for something else - please ignore. The way I loaded the data using `read.table` was just because of how you put it in your question. In general it's more reproducible to use `dput(df)`. I'll update my answer using that format so it should reproduce exactly for you.

Comment: @VIX - try cleaning your environment and starting a new R session and then running the reprex I just posted and see how it goes.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try it in the next days